# my code to add items to a list box of form1 from a datagrid view from form2 a isnt working. but it works for inserting to a textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox

form 2

```
public string[] thislistboxitems;
private string pVal;
public string PassVal
{
    get { return pVal; }
    set { pVal = value; }
}

private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Text = pVal;
}
```

form 1

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
{
    int selectedCellCount = dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

    if (selectedCellCount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedCellCount; i++)
        {
            int column = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex;
            int row = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex;
            f.PassVal = dataGridView1[column, row].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Form2 create a public method that you could call from Form1

```
public void AddToListBox(string itemText)
{
    this.ListBox1.Items.Add(itemText);
}
```

and in Form1 change your loop to call this method

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
int selectedCellCount = dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

if (selectedCellCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedCellCount; i++)
    {
        int column = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex;
        int row = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex;
        f.AddToListBox(dataGridView1[column, row].Value.ToString());
    }
}
f,Show();
```

Comment: thank you so much . the code worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the selected value as item in a listbox.

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(pVal);
}
```